# How to get Facebook App (iFrame) to auto popup permission request

Tags: facebook, api

I am developing a Facebook app, but in an iFrame, however it seems I have to get the users to click the Facebook login button, I was wondering how I could skip that part and just ask the user for permission?

I downloaded the PHP-SDK, and used the example script that came with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 

    $app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;
    $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
    $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    if(empty($code)) {
        $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);

        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    }

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&client_secret="
        . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

    $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" . $access_token;

    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

    echo("Hello " . $user->name);

?>
```